# Sortable table rows using one column

Tags: jquery, sorting, html-table, contenteditable, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm not sure if the title describes my problem. I'm trying to make table where values can be changed inline (using `contenteditable`) and which is sortable.

Unfortunately, I have no idea how to combine these features together. The HTML looks like this:

```
<table id="sort">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>#</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Last Name</th>
      <th>Position</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td contenteditable="true">John</td>
      <td contenteditable="true">Doe</td>
      <td><img src="images/3-lines.png" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td contenteditable="true">John</td>
      <td contenteditable="true">Doe</td>
      <td><img src="images/3-lines.png" /></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

The JS looks like this:

```
var fixHelperModified = function(e, tr) {
    var $originals = tr.children();
    var $helper = tr.clone();
    $helper.children().each(function(index) {
        $(this).width($originals.eq(index).width())
    });
    return $helper;
},
    updateIndex = function(e, ui) {
        $('td.index', ui.item.parent()).each(function (i) {
            $(this).html(i + 1);
        });
    };

$("#sort tbody").sortable({
    helper: fixHelperModified,
    stop: updateIndex
}).disableSelection();
```

I would like to keep contenteditable attribute. The user should be able to reorder rows by draging "3-lines.png" icon which is on the far right cell.

It's possible?

Comment: Can you use any plugins?

Answer (score 0):

If you can add a jquery plugin, use DataTables, it does what you want, I think.

https://editor.datatables.net/examples/inline-editing/simple

Comment: I just thought of posting it and I posted the code too!

Comment: You should have posted the code to enable the sorting on the last col too :P

Just kidding, in case of dataTable is a solution, read here too:
https://datatables.net/reference/option/columnDefs.targets

Comment: Yea... Worthless to make it work in the fiddle. I am deleting my answer.